# How to convert WADL to WSDL?

Tags: xml, object, wsdl, cloud, wadl

I want to convert a WADL file to WSDL file using my converter. The Converter has a WADL file as input and a WSDL file as output. To convert a WADL file to a WSDL file, the Converter follows the steps below:

1. The Converter receives a WADL file as input, then the Parser parses
   WADL file and takes out the needful data to construct a WADL object.
   This WADL object is created by filling classes with necessary data.
2. It instantiates a new WSDL object from WADL object.
3. Using the WSDL object, the Converter creates a new WSDL file
   corresponding to the WADL file.

So what i need is the mapping between XML-Object, Object-Object and Object-XML. How can i do it? and is exist some framework to do that?